# C# code connection to mysql in localhost. Is provider wrong?

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string

I have already installed mysql connector 6.7.4 and following reference is already added in code

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

I am using this string to connect database

```
string connStr = ("Provider = MySQLProv; SERVER =localhost; DATABASE=test;User ID=root;Password=");
OdbcConnection conn1 = new OdbcConnection();
conn1.ConnectionString = connStr;
OdbcCommand cmd1 = conn1.CreateCommand();
cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM patientinfo WHERE medicareNo = " + "" + p.getMedicare() + "";
conn1.Open();
```

It says,

```
ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

What did i do wrong ?? I have sqltest database with the required table.

update: odbc connector 5.2 is installed and used as:

```
using System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
```

Comment: Take a look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/. Have you tried removing the spaces from your connection string?

Comment: I tried from connectionstrings. Couldnt come up. Tried removing the spaces: didnt work. It shows the error pointed in conn1.open() and gives the above mentioned error message.

Comment: You need a `;` at the end of your password in your connection string.

Comment: @Rohan , tried. Still didnt work.It seems my odbc connection driver is not used by the program. It shows 
using System.Data.Odbc;
is there as unused directive.

Answer (score 0):

When installing your MySql Server did you install the service in a specific port? this could be a potential problem, just in case try this connection string which specifies the port

3306 is the default MySql port, yours may differ if you specified it during installation.

```
Server=yourServerName;Port=3306;Database=test;Uid=root;
Pwd=yourPassword;
```